# Converting created_at UTC to Eastern Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My model has (by default) generated a "created_at" field in the database that stores when the row was inserted into the database in UTC.

In my controller, I retrieve the data from the database and try to convert the value to Eastern time with the following:

```
data["created_at"] = data["created_at"].in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
```

When I view the output of the above code, it looks like my "created_at" value is still in UTC instead of Eastern time. Any thoughts?  Thanks.

EDIT:
To answer a comment, when I inspect the value of created_at coming from the database, it's value is: 2015-01-31 18:34:51

Comment: please provide the value you get for `data["created_at"]`..

Answer (score 1):

In your config in application.rb add timezone

`config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'`

it will keep your dates in db in utc, but display with specified timezone

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp is still the timestamp.  You're simply specifying a possible way to display it.

What might make more sense is to leave it in UTC in the database (a good standard) and just localize it upon display in whatever way makes sense.

For example, with a logging app we wrote, hovering over the UTC timestamp gives you the localized timestamp for yourself based on your user profile in the system.